# Changing color of characters in label box dynamically in JAVA

Tags: java, html, swing

I am creating a typing test game in java using Swing Jframe form.

In the program I am comparing the characters of textfield (input) and the labelbox (predefined sample). If the characters are same in the two, then the color of that character shall turn green in the label box otherwise red.

For example: Sample text in label box: This is sample

If the first character entered in the textfield box is T, 'T' in label box should turn green, else Red.

I have tried using the `label.setForeground()` option, it turns the entire text in that particular color.

I have tried using `label.setText(String.format("<html> text1 <font color='red'> text2 </font></html>"));` option, it turns only the text between the codes into the respective color.

Please, guide me through, if there is an html feature I should know or java feature that I should use to achieve this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the color of that character shall turn green in the label box otherwise red.

Don't use a JLabel (and HTML) for this.

Instead use a `JTextPane`. You can easily change the attributes of a single character.

Simple example to get you started:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "Hello" );

//  Define some character attributes

SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

//  Change attributes on some existing text

StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 1, green, false);
```

Comment: How can I compare the characters of input string entered in the `JInputField` with the characters of `JTextPane` and accordingly change the color of the characters in `JTextPane`?